# PHP Preg_split selecting the internal contents of an HTML tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a string which contains text in a variety of HTML tags. I need to clean the HTML tags themselves, so the data between the `<` and `>` such that

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify;">1939&nbsp;After considerable negotiation between the Kemp estate and the Dunwich Trusts, the charter was purchased and returned to Dunwich.</p>
```

becomes

```
<p>1939&nbsp;After considerable negotiation between the Kemp estate and the Dunwich Trusts, the charter was purchased and returned to Dunwich.</p>
```

I did this with

```
$value = preg_replace("/<p[^>]+>/", "<p>", $value);
```

But I need to preserve the contents of the `<a>` tags, within the string, but also clean the excess such as that `style` content.

I intend to do this by running a loop and extracting the anchor tag and then working on each anchor tag, splitting at the spaces and keeping the exploded array values starting with `href=`,`title=` etc etc.

**But now my issue is this:**

How can I split a string to take the contents of the `<a>` tag with a Preg_split regex ?

If I do

```
$value = preg_split("/<a[^>]+>/", $value);
```

Then value returns the content *outside* of the anchor tag, rather than inside the anchor tag. I do not know what is inside the anchor tag, so can only base the pattern on `<a`.......`>`

I want to make an array of anchor tags from a string, such that :

```
<h2>Headlines</h2>
<a href="index.php?id=11">Charter Returned to Dunwich in 1939</a>  
<a href="index.php?id=10">Thomas Gardner Visits Dunwich</a>  
<a href="index.php?id=9">Treasure Chest Purchases</a>  
<a href="index.php?id=8">Dunwich Charter 1215</a>  
<a href="index.php?id=7">Why did Dunwich have a Charter?</a>  
</div>
```

can give me:

```
$array[0] = 'a href="index.php?id=11"';
$array[1] = 'a href="index.php?id=10"';
$array[2] = 'a href="index.php?id=9"';
$array[3] = 'a href="index.php?id=8"';
$array[4] = 'a href="index.php?id=7"';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use just `preg_match_all`:

```
$re = "/<a[^>]+>/"; 
$str = "<h2>Headlines</h2>\n<a href=\"index.php?id=11\">Charter Returned to Dunwich in 1939</a>  \n<a href=\"index.php?id=10\">Thomas Gardner Visits Dunwich</a>  \n<a href=\"index.php?id=9\">Treasure Chest Purchases</a>  \n<a href=\"index.php?id=8\">Dunwich Charter 1215</a>  \n<a href=\"index.php?id=7\">Why did Dunwich have a Charter?</a>  \n</div> "; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

`$matches` will contain:

```
a href="index.php?id=11"
a href="index.php?id=10"
a href="index.php?id=9"
a href="index.php?id=8"
a href="index.php?id=7"
```

Have a look at the [demo program](http://goo.gl/mWJWt8).